# Matching codons using lists, dictionaries and loops

Tags: python, loops, python-2.7, dictionary, bioinformatics

This is one of the more difficult problems I have faced so far so excuse my for not providing a substantial attempt at doing it.

I want a program that prints matching codons in the format:

```
AAA : TTT
GGG : CCC
TTT : AAA
CCC : GGG
    .
    .
    .
```

Here is what I did:

```
pairs = {'A':'T','C':'G','T':'A','G':'C'}
codonsA = ['AAG', 'TAC', 'CGG', 'GAT', 'TTG', 'GTG', 'CAT', 'GGC', 'ATT', 'TCT']
codonsB = ['TAA', 'CTA', 'AAC', 'TTC', 'AGA', 'CAC', 'CCG', 'ATG', 'GCC', 'GTA']
for A in codonsA:
    print A + ' :',
    for B in codonsB:
        print B,
    print

#OUTPUT:

AAG : TAA CTA AAC TTC AGA CAC CCG ATG GCC GTA
TAC : TAA CTA AAC TTC AGA CAC CCG ATG GCC GTA
CGG : TAA CTA AAC TTC AGA CAC CCG ATG GCC GTA
GAT : TAA CTA AAC TTC AGA CAC CCG ATG GCC GTA
TTG : TAA CTA AAC TTC AGA CAC CCG ATG GCC GTA
GTG : TAA CTA AAC TTC AGA CAC CCG ATG GCC GTA
CAT : TAA CTA AAC TTC AGA CAC CCG ATG GCC GTA
GGC : TAA CTA AAC TTC AGA CAC CCG ATG GCC GTA
ATT : TAA CTA AAC TTC AGA CAC CCG ATG GCC GTA
TCT : TAA CTA AAC TTC AGA CAC CCG ATG GCC GTA
```

What I need to do now is to get rid off 9 codons from B from each row on the right of the colon and leave only the one codon on the right that matches the codon from A on the left. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need that `codonsB` list.  A codon maps onto its anticodon complement 1:1.

```
def anticodon(codon):
    """returns the anticodon complement for a given codon"""
    return ''.join(pairs[c] for c in codon)

anticodon('AAG')
Out[5]: 'TTC'
```

You're free to check if each element in `codonsA` has an anticodon in `codonsB`, if you need to make that check.

```
all(anticodon(c) in codonsB for c in codonsA)
Out[6]: True
```

And the output I think you were originally looking for:

```
for codon in codonsA:
    print '{} : {}'.format(codon,anticodon(codon))

AAG : TTC
TAC : ATG
CGG : GCC
GAT : CTA
TTG : AAC
GTG : CAC
CAT : GTA
GGC : CCG
ATT : TAA
TCT : AGA
```

Comment: Well, the question says I have to use both `codonsA` and `codonsB` as well as the dictionary `pairs` and for loop. I am self learning though so it isn't like I have to do as the textbook says so thank you very much for the answer but I would love to see it being done the other way too.

Comment: I can't really address the approach the question had in mind, since it is strictly unnecessary to have that second list of complements.  A codon has an anticodon, it's just how DNA works :-)

Comment: That makes sense, it is really pointless to have a second codon, even in biology they only worry about the first codon since it is easy to figure out the matching codon. Thank you very much, I will use your answer :)

Comment: Where does these `pairs` function come?

Comment: @llopis check the OP.  It's a `dict`.